# Aside from going into bootcamps, what’s another way to build case studies? I have a few ideas but I’m not sure how to build it without a main guide?

Tags: user-research, usability-testing, portfolio, case-studies

So as a context: I've already done a bootcamp last year but in that bootcamp, we didn't make a lot of case studies. Just one. I need more but I'm not sure how I'm going to recruit participants into the research/usability testing and also the thought of not having any guidance throughout the entire process is kind of scaring me a bit.

Comment: This is not really a UXSE question, but what it is that you are having specific concerns about that you think building case studies will help with? If it is experience and things that you need to look out for, there are many questions relating to recruiting participants, doing research and usability testing that you can look up or ask :)

Comment: @MichaelLai Thank you so much for that! I'm trying to build a stronger portfolio. I've noticed that while I'm getting interviews, the one case study that I have doesn't really tell a connected and compelling story and that's what they look for in a nutshell when looking for someone to hire.